# 'astro' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: npm, astrojs

I was able to run my website before but now it won't let me. I tried to download old code from my branch history and it's not still working. Not sure what I did. I tried looking up ways to resolve but couldn't find anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: PWSH SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 7):

I ran `npm install` again and it solved the problem.